# How do I run multivariable correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a large amount of data which I'd like to divide by multiple variables, as in the following plot:

[image]

There are a total of 63 plots here, divided by 3 variables (`rows`, `cols` and `fram`). In reality, of course, `valuex` and `valuey` have more than 3 observations. I would like to find the Pearson correlation for every single one of these as efficiently as possible and I'm kinda blanking on ideas.

Here's some example data with which the plot was created:

```r
example_df <- data.frame(rows = rep(c('r1', 'r2', 'r3'), 63),
                         cols = rep(letters[1:7], 27),
                         fram = rep(c('X', 'Y', 'Z'), each = 63),
                         valuex = rnorm(189),
                         valuey = rnorm(189))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to `group_by` multiple variables then `summarize` to get the `cor` between `valuex` and `valuey` for each subgroup:

```r
library(dplyr)

example_df %>% group_by(rows, cols, fram) %>% summarize(cor = cor(valuex, valuey))
#> # A tibble: 63 x 4
#> # Groups:   rows, cols [21]
#>    rows  cols  fram     cor
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 r1    a     X     -0.709
#>  2 r1    a     Y      0.178
#>  3 r1    a     Z     -0.597
#>  4 r1    b     X     -0.338
#>  5 r1    b     Y      0.981
#>  6 r1    b     Z     -0.731
#>  7 r1    c     X      0.945
#>  8 r1    c     Y     -0.913
#>  9 r1    c     Z      0.177
#> 10 r1    d     X      0.999
#> # ... with 53 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!